# Format time in ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I have consulted a lot of websites and tried many ways to format the time but to no avail. What is the solution?
My code:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public TimeSpan? TimeOpen { get; set; }
```

I use `Postman` and raw `"timeOpen": "09:00:00", "timeClose": "18:00:00"` can POST. But in `Swagger` it show example is:

```
"timeOpen": 
{
    "ticks": 0,
    "days": 0,
    "hours": 0,
    "milliseconds": 0,
    "minutes": 0,
    "seconds": 0
},
"timeClose": 
{
    "ticks": 0,
    "days": 0,
    "hours": 0,
    "milliseconds": 0,
    "minutes": 0,
    "seconds": 0
},
```

How to change it to `HH:mm:ss` in `Swagger`?
I tried `{0:HH:mm:ss}`,`{0:HH\:mm\:ss}`,`{0:HH\\:mm\\:ss}`,`{0:HH\\-mm\\-ss}`,`@{0:HH\\:mm\\:ss}`,`{0:g}`,... but it didn't work.
Is it because `Swagger` doesn't support it yet?

Comment: why are you using TimeSpan?

Comment: Because I think  TimeOpen and TimeClose are ```TIME``` type not ```DATETIME```.

Comment: What library do you use - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, NSwag, something else? You need to tweak the OpenAPI definition generation so that the `timeOpen` and `timeClose` properties are generated as `type: string` with an optional regex pattern like `pattern: ^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(?::\d\d)?$`  and an optional example value like `example: '09:00:00'`. Your library should have annotations or special methods for that. E.g. Swashbuckle has [`ISchemaFilter`](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#schema-filters).

Comment: So the output coming accordingly on postman? can you share your method which you are calling?

Answer (score -1):

It is a date-time range, get open and close time then compute the difference, then will come the usage of timespan when it's very important to close or open at particular exact Time.

```
public DateTime Start { get; set; }
public DateTime End { get; set; }
public TimeSpan Duration => End - Start;
```